# The variables pop-up window keeps coming up even when '&' is not used anywhere in code

Tags: variables, popup, toad

Below are the version details for my TOAD:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

As per my understanding, the variables pop-up comes up if there is an `&` in the code. But there is no `&` in my code.

Please let me know if there could be any other reason as to why this pop-up is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be a '&', it might as well be a ? or a :1 kind of parameter.

Comment: I have a similar issue and it seems to be caused by some text in a string comparison I have: column like '& phone' and that & in my string is triggering it. Is there some way to make it so I can make a comparison on that without triggering the variable?